# Linux - find files created within the last X seconds

Tags: linux, unix, find

Can `find` be used to find files created within the last 5 seconds?

I am using a command like the following:

```
$ find /myPath -name "sun*" -type f  -cmin -1
```

which lists files created within the last minute but I need a higher resolution.

Answer (score 4):

`GNU find`'s option `-cmin` accepts real numbers. Since 5 seconds is 0.083 minutes, you can do the following:

```
$ find /myPath -name "sun*" -type f -cmin -0.083
```

Comment: No it did not work,, its giving below error..                                                                                                                                 $ find /myPath -name "sun*" -type f -cmin -0.083
find: invalid argument `-0.083' to `-cmin'

Comment: @SunilGowda Depending on your locales, you may have to use "," as floating point separator. Either use `$ LANG=C find /myPath -name "sun*" -type f -cmin -0.083` or `$ find /myPath -name "sun*" -type f -cmin -0,083`